# How do I Sort from selected in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have multiple "Cat Types" TacoCats, SpaceCats, FatCats. I need to sort through my cats. One condition is that TacoCats cannot be shown if they are under the age of 65. So they must meet all other filter conditions as well as not having an age < 65. How do I change this expression so that only TacoCats are affected by the condition of having to be over the age of 65? To clarify i need all of the other cats regardless of age and that condition to only affect the "TacoCats"

```
public void SortOutOnlyActiveOrPaidCats()
{
    AllCats = AllCats.Where 
        (x => 
            (x.CatStatus == "Active" || x.CatStatus == "Paid") 
            && (x.CatCode == "1" || x.CatCode == "2" || x.CatCode == "3" || x.CatCode == "4") 
            && (x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G"));
}
```

This is the original change that I tried as well.

```
 (x = > ((x.CatStatus == "Active" || x.CatStatus == "Paid") && (x.CatCode == "1" || x.CatCode == "2" || x.CatCode == "3" || x.CatCode == "4") && (x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G") && (x.CatType != "TacoCat")) || ((x.CatStatus == "Active" || x.CatStatus == "Paid") && (x.CatCode == "1" || x.CatCode == "2" || x.CatCode == "3" || x.CatCode == "4") && (x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G") && (x.Age >= 65) && (x.PolicyType == "Taco Cats")) )
```

Comment: did you have a question?

Comment: So...  What's your question?

Comment: `&& (x.age >= 65 || x.isTaco)` ?

Comment: @Martijn Not quite, should be `!x.isTaco`

Comment: as an aside...  How is AllCats defined?  due to the way linq expressions work, I'm guessing you need a .ToList() at the end of that line.

Comment: What are all of your conditions?  You have a very complicated Boolean and you may not need all the conditions in the posted code.  We may need to simplify your logical equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we can simplify it by putting the statuses and code into an array and using `Contains`, then add the extra condition for TacoCat ages, which if you simplify it is essentially "where cat is over 65 or it's not a taco cat":

```
public void SortOutOnlyActiveOrPaidCats()
{
    var validStatuses = new [] { "Active", "Paid" };
    var validCodes = new [] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

    AllCats = AllCats.Where(x => 
        validStatuses.Contains(x.CatStatus) &&
        validCodes.Contains(x.CatCode) &&
        x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G" &&
        (x.CatType != "TacoCat" || x.Age >= 65)
    );
}
```

Comment: I really like that answer. Does that do the same thing as this? 

(x =  >
((x.CatStatus == "Active" || x.CatStatus == "Paid")
&& (x.CatCode == "1" || x.CatCode == "2" || x.CatCode == "3" || x.CatCode == "4")
&& (x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G")
&& (x.CatType != "TacoCat"))

||
((x.CatStatus == "Active" || x.CatStatus == "Paid")
&& (x.CatCode == "1" || x.CatCode == "2" || x.CatCode == "3" || x.CatCode == "4")
&& (x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G")
&& (x.Age >= 65)
&& (x.PolicyType == "Taco Cats"))
);

Answer (score 0):

```
            public void SortOutOnlyActiveOrPaidCats()
  {
        AllCats = AllCats.Where 
        (x => 

            x.Age < 65 &&
            ((x.CatStatus == "Active" || x.CatStatus == "Paid") 
            && (x.CatCode == "1" || x.CatCode == "2" ||  x.CatCode == "3" || x.CatCode == "4") 
            && (x.CatEnrollmentCode != "G")));
    }
```

Here you first make sure that you get only cats that are younger 65 yrs. Then you filter using the listed conditions

Happy coding and happy petting ;-)

Comment: The original question states that only `TacoCats` are subject to the `Age < 65` requirement, whereas this filters out *any* cat that doesn't meet that condition.

Comment: It's also back to front

Comment: You are right Joshua Shearer 
I agree with DavidG Answer